# How to create another Maven project inside the Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I was following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOCeQYbQPPU&t=2845s

https://github.com/shabbirdwd53/spring-security-tutorial

Inside the project, there are 3 project modules. I had problems opening this project after downloading, in my eclipse, I got a weird amount of packages outside the project folders.

Then I tried to create a maven project `spring-security-tutorial`, then inside it, I tried to create the `OAuth-authorization-server` project. But the project folder appears outside of the `spring-security tutorial`, not inside the `spring-security tutorial`.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module Does this help ?

Comment: It did help, thank you. I had defined in super pom everything before, but the problem was when I clicked right-click on the super project, I thought a new Spring Boot app will be added inside it. But no, I needed to set a path in creating the Spring Starter project window. But your comment helped to understand modules in Maven in general. Thank you @Harsh